# SQL Developer error when I insert multiple values into table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm populating a table with values, but it gives me an error at line 3 that says:

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

This is my code:

```
INSERT INTO DB_accounts
    VALUES
        (1001, 'a1', 'pass001'),
        (1002, 'a2', 'pass002'),
        (1003, 'a3', 'pass003'),
        (1004, 'a4', 'pass004'),
        (1005, 'a5', 'pass005'),
        (1006, 'a6', 'pass006'),
        (1007, 'a7', 'pass007'),
        (1008, 'a8', 'pass008'),
        (1009, 'a9', 'pass009'),
        (1010, 'a10', 'pass010');
```

And this is the code for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE DB_accounts (
    id_account NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Oracle INSERT VALUES can only insert one row at the time.

Comment: @jarlh - not true.  See INSERT ALL

Comment: @OldProgrammer, good point. Anyway, Oracle doesn't support "F641, Row and table constructors" - which OP is trying to use.